# i am unable to text on button in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i add button column in datagridview named datagridview1.button column added successfully in datagridview but no show any text on button.
my code is:

```
    Dim btn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn
    btn.Name = "choice1"
    btn.HeaderText = "choice1"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09zv6.png)

how i can texxt on button??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this

```
 btn.Name = "choice1"
 btn.HeaderText = "choice1"
 btn.Text = "choice1"
 btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
 DataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn)
```

now this text on button in gridview.